# Templates - Accessing protected typedefs in base class

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11

I've been using the tree container classes from [here](https://github.com/erikerlandson/st_tree).

In Visual Studio 2013 everything is fine (after one minor fix), but my application is cross-platform, so now I'm trying to get it to compile in Xcode 7.2.1 (Clang 1.0), and all hell breaks loose.

I have a multitude of errors; the one that I've been looking at, and can't fathom is this.. (I've trimmed out some bits for clarity)

```
template <typename Tree, typename Data, typename Compare>
struct node_ordered
: public node_base< Tree, 
                    node_ordered<Tree, Data, Compare>, 
                    multiset<   node_ordered<Tree, Data, Compare>*, 
                                ptr_less_data<Compare>, 
                                typename Tree::allocator_type> 
                                > 
    {
    typedef Tree tree_type;
    typedef typename Tree::allocator_type allocator_type;
    typedef node_ordered<Tree, Data, Compare> node_type;
    typedef multiset<node_type*, ptr_less_data<Compare>, allocator_type> cs_type;
    typedef node_base<Tree, node_type, cs_type> base_type;

    typedef typename base_type::iterator iterator;
    typedef typename base_type::const_iterator const_iterator;

    protected:
    typedef typename base_type::cs_iterator cs_iterator;
    typedef typename base_type::cs_const_iterator cs_const_iterator;
```

Now the last two lines generate an error,

```
error: 'cs_iterator' is a protected member of 'st_tree::detail::node_base...
```

It's true that cs_iterator is a protected member of that class, but said class is the base class, so surely it should work?  It does in Visual Studio, and it would seem in G++ (I deduce this from comments relating to issue #16).

I've tried copying and pasting the base class definition directly from the : public node_base<.. line to check that it's not an issue with typedefs, and I get the same error.

As I said, this code compiles and works just fine in Visual Studio 2013. Now I've got used to Xcode/Clang being rather stricter on syntax that Visual C++, but this (and the other errors I'm getting) have me mystified.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this with a shorter test example, with a simple `struct Base` and `struct Derived: Base` ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, so people don't waste time trying to help me.

It turns out that this error, and indeed most of the errors I was seeing, were red herrings.

I thought the reason for the differences I was getting compiling in XCode rather than Visual Studio were due to compiler differences (this is usually the culprit).

But it turns out it was due to differences in the libraries.

XCode uses the LLVM libcxx, which includes some compile time checks that others don't.

For example in the vector<> definition, we have

```
    static_assert((is_same<typename allocator_type::value_type, value_type>::value),
              "Allocator::value_type must be same type as value_type");
```

Now in the st_tree container, there were places where the developer had used the allocator given for the tree value type in vector declarations for internal values.

Now, when the compiler hit that static_assert failure, it popped up an error, as I would expect, but then continued on in a very broken manner, giving a load of misleading errors, such as the one that prompted me to post this question.

I've informed the developer of st_tree of the issues with his code.